# Loopback conditional data validation

Tags: javascript, strongloop, loopback

How can I define some validation rules depending on some conditions in request body.
For example, I want to validate that post description field is set only if the post is published (isPublished flag equals true), something like:

```js
module.exports = function(Post) {
if(req.body.isPublished === true) {
    Post.validatesPresenceOf('description');
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate some more?

Comment: @nitte93user3232918 I have elaborated more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, you can use `options` parameter

`Post.validatesPresenceOf('description', {if: 'isPublished'});`

Ref: [#validatable-validatespresenceof](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#validatable-validatespresenceof)

Answer (score 2):

> May be you are looking for something like this

```
Post.observe('before save',(ctx,next)=>{
  //if post is created
  if(ctx.isNewInstance) {
    if(ctx.instance.isPublished)
      Post.validatesPresenceOf('description');
  }
  //if post is updated
  else{
    if(ctx.data.isPublished)
      Post.validatesPresenceOf('description');
  }
return next();
})
```

Comment: I tried this, and it seems to add the validation check on all future instances of the model each time you call a 'validates...' method, which then ignores the if conditionals in this code.